# Is there an integral number `k` satisfying the equation `a[n] = k^2`?

Tags: sequence

I have a sequence `a[n]` with

$$a(n+1)=4 a(n)-2 a(n-1),\quad a(0) = 1,\ a(1) = 28.$$

I use

```
RSolve[{a[n + 1] == 4 a[n] - 2  a[n - 1], a[0] == 1, a[1] == 28}, a, n]
```

and got

```
{{a -> Function[{n}, 1/2 ((2 - Sqrt[2])^n - 13 Sqrt[2] (2 - Sqrt[2])^n + (2 + Sqrt[2])^n + 13 Sqrt[2] (2 + Sqrt[2])^n)]}}
```

Now I tried to find an integer `k` such that `a[n]==k^2`, `k` from 1 to 100.

```
Reduce[{1/2 ((2 - Sqrt[2])^n - 13 Sqrt[2] (2 - Sqrt[2])^n + (2 + Sqrt[2])^n + 13 Sqrt[2] (2 + Sqrt[2])^n) == k, 1 <= k <= 100,2 <= n <= 100}, {k, n}, Integers]
```

I got the answer

```
False
```

Is there an integral number `k` that satisfies the equation `a[n] == k^2` ($n \neq 0$)?

Comment: `a[0]==1==1^2`?

Comment: Did you mean to write `== k^2` rather than `== k`?

Comment: @JimB `a[n]=1, 4, 9, ....`

Comment: Sorry I'm not understanding.  What does `a[n]=1, 4, 9, ....` have to do with your code `Reduce[{1/2 ((2 - Sqrt[2])^n - 13 Sqrt[2] (2 - Sqrt[2])^n + (2 + Sqrt[2])^n + 13 Sqrt[2] (2 + Sqrt[2])^n) == k, 1 <= k <= 100,2 <= n <= 100}, {k, n}, Integers]` which has `== k` rather than `== k^2` ?

Comment: Would the following be a more direct brute force approach:  `nMax = 1000; Select[
 Sqrt[Table[
   Expand[1/
      2 ((2 - Sqrt[2])^n - 
       13 Sqrt[2] (2 - Sqrt[2])^n + (2 + Sqrt[2])^n + 
       13 Sqrt[2] (2 + Sqrt[2])^n)], {n, nMax}]], # \[Element] 
   Integers &]`.

Comment: I don't think *Mathematica* can prove that there isn't such an element (apart from $n=1$). Maybe try the [mathematics stack exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: No perfect squares in the first 100000 elements.